# Binary Search or Insertion Sort with list view [Visual Basic .net]

Tags: vb.net, sorting, ms-access, binary-search, insertion-sort

Recently when creating a program for my client as part of my computing project in visual basic .net I've came across a problem, which looks like following; In order to receive additional marks for my program I must take an advantage of either Binary Search or Insertion Sort subroutine declared recursively, so far the only place I can use it on is my View form which displays all reports generated by program but the problem with this is since I'm using MS Access to store my data all of the data is downloaded and placed in listview in load part of form. So the only way I can use it is by running it on listview which is a major problem for me due to the fact that I'm not very experienced in vb.

For binary search I have tried downloading all of the items in specified by user column into an array but that's the bit I was struggling on the most because I'm unable to download all items from only one column into an array. Also instead of searching every single column user specifies in my form in which column item is located (For example "19/02/2013" In Column "Date"), In my opinion if I manage to download every single entry in specified column into an array it should allow me to run binary search later on therefore completing the algorithm. Here's what I've got so far.

```
    Sub BinarySearch(ByVal Key As String, ByVal lowindex As String, ByVal highindex As String, ByVal temp() As String)
    Dim midpoint As Integer

    If lowindex > highindex Then
        MsgBox("Search Failed")
    Else
        midpoint = (highindex + lowindex) / 2
        If temp(midpoint) = Key Then
            MsgBox("found at location " & midpoint)
        ElseIf Key < temp(midpoint) Then
            Call BinarySearch(Key, lowindex, midpoint, temp)
        ElseIf Key > temp(midpoint) Then
            Call BinarySearch(Key, midpoint, highindex, temp)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim Key As String = txtSearch.Text
    Dim TargetColumn As String = Me.lstOutput.Columns(cmbColumns.Text).Index
    Dim lowindex As Integer = 0
    Dim highindex As Integer = lstOutput.Items.Count - 1
    'Somehow all of the items in Target column must be placed in temp array
    Dim temp(Me.lstOutput.Items.Count - 1) As String

    ' BinarySearch(Key, lowindex, highindex, temp)
End Sub
```

For Insertion sort i don't even have a clue how to start, and the thing is that I have to use my own subroutine instead of calling system libraries which will do it for me.
Code which I have to use looks like following:

```
Private Sub InsertionSort()
Dim First As Integer = 1
Dim Last As Integer = Me.lstOutput.
Dim CurrentPtr, CurrentValue, Ptr As Integer
For CurrentPtr = First + 1 To Last
CurrentValue = A(CurrentPtr)
Ptr = CurrentPtr - 1
While A(Ptr) > CurrentValue And Ptr > 0
A(Ptr + 1) = A(Ptr)
Ptr -= 1
End While
A(Ptr + 1) = CurrentValue
Next
Timer1.Enabled = False
lblTime.Text = tick.ToString
End Sub
```

Any ideas on how to implement this code will be very appreciated, and please keep in my mind that I'm not very experienced in this language

Comment: So, what are you really asking here? Is it that you are having difficulty retrieving a column from an Access table and storing the values in an Array? Is that what is keeping you from getting "additional marks" from your "client"?

Comment: Basically I'm asking for help in general about how to implement one of these algorithms for data in listview, or how to download all of the data from specific column to an array

Comment: Thats not how a ListView sort works, especially if it is bound (if that is what "download" means).  You need to get the db data into something like an ArrayList, sort it this way or that, then post the results to the ListView.  To sort once it is in the ListView, in order to sort on a specific column, you'd need a custom `ListViewSorter` which only provides the item vs Item comparison, the LV does the actual sort.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might give you a place to begin. If you already have a ListView with "stuff" in it you could add a button to the form with the following code to copy the `Text` property for each item into an array:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myArray(Me.ListView1.Items.Count - 1) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    ' load array
    For i = 0 To Me.ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        myArray(i) = Me.ListView1.Items(i).Text
    Next

    ' show the results
    Dim s As String = ""
    For i = 0 To UBound(myArray)
        s &= String.Format("myArray({0}): {1}", i, myArray(i)) & vbCrLf
    Next
    MsgBox(s, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "myArray Contents")

    ' now go ahead and manipulate the array as needed
    ' ...
End Sub
```